# PHP: How to compare/save different ARRAYS from different WHILE loops and send data to AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I am working with two different tables that are in different servers.
I am trying to compare the USERNAME field values from table "workstation_userlogged" and 
the MEMO_CODE field value (they are usernames) from table "telephony". I get the "memo_code" values with the use of a Stored Procedure as you will see in the code below.

How can I save all the results returned from both tables, loop through them to match all usernames and then save the data so it can be returned with AJAX? This script will only run when an AJAX request button is clicked. So, I need to bring the data back and display it like so:

If matching usernames from both tables:

```
user: JOE  time: 300
```

If no matching usernames:

```
user: MARC  time: N/A
```

Some usernames from "workstation_userlogged" do not exist in the other table and vice versa.

I know it has to do with handling arrays and all but I've been stuck for hours and wasn't able to accomplish it.I need to clarify things please ask.

Thanks in advance!

**map.php HTML/AJAX: How do I fix this?**

```
<!-- Show the results here-->
<div id="resultdiv" class="resultdiv" style="display:none"> </div>  

<div id="aht"><!--aht button--> 
    <button id="aht_button">AHT</button>    
</div><!--aht button--> 

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#aht').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url : "show_aht.php",
                    data: {  }, // pass data here
                    success : function(data){

                    }//end success
                });//end ajax
              });//end click
            });//end rdy
```

**show_aht.php: when AJAX request is sent**

```
<?php
```

Stored PRocedure just to show what I did:

```
    //get the StoredProcedure from the "query" field in the overlay table 
    //and store it as a variable for later use for the AHT button
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_overlay_result)){
        $sp_value = $row['query']; 
    }
```

Table workstation_userlogged: 
The results from this WHILE LOOP need to be matched with the results of the StoredProcedure below

```
    //the displayed users values will have to be matched with memo_code
    $user_data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_user_result)){
        $user_data[] = "user: " .$row['username'];
    }
```

This is where I am trying to compare both usernames and bring the data back
to map.php but had no luck.

```
    /****************************************************
    Execute the sp_value query when AHT button is clicked
    /****************************************************/
    //loop the result set
    $memo_data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbh2_result)){   
        $memo_data[] = $row['memo_code'] . " " . $row['avg_handle_time'];
    }



    /*THIS ISNT WORKING*/
    foreach($memo_data as $v){
        foreach($user_data as $m){
            if($v['memo_code'] == $m['username'])
                echo " user: " .$m['username']. " time: " . $v['avg_handle_time'] . "<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why are you json encoding your arrays before your comparison loop?

Comment: how else am I suposed to compare both arrays? thats where im lost

Comment: Can you add var_dump($user_array) after the sql call but before the json encode and show me the output?

Comment: I cant do it after the sql call since I need to initialize the $user_array. So I did it after the json_encode($user_data) this is the output **string(1240) "["user: EAGC","user: THRH","user: GRGRA3","user: BZMPU","user: LINEL2","user: RUPIE1","user: RIELM","user: FRVOU","user: CAPAP3","user: DAMUL9","user: LUKHO1","user: VIMUN3","user: EROLI2","user: VATRE1","user: BRMIC4"]"**

Comment: You understand that is a string and not an array right? Please get rid of the json_encode you don't need to initialize the array just output $user_data directly.

Comment: heres the result of var_dump($user_data) **array(88) { [0]=> string(12) "user: MICCH3" [1]=> string(11) "user: OXGOR" [2]=> string(11) "user: FLZAR" [3]=> string(12) "user: AISAI2" [4]=> string(10) "user: HCZR" [5]=> string(10) "user: WLAH" [6]=> string(11) "user: ETWEF" [7]=> string(12)}**  yea I didnt realize till now.. I still dont know how to compare both arrays for matching values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution basically I wasnt`t comparing arrays properly so here below is the new comparison.

```
    $user_data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_user_result)){
        $user_data[] = $row['username'];
    }


    /****************************************************/
    //loop the result set
    $memo_data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbh2_result)){   
        $memo_data[] = array("memo_code" => $row['memo_code'],
                           "avg_handle_time" => $row['avg_handle_time']);
    }
/**comparing usernames from both arrays*/
foreach($memo_data as $v){
        foreach($user_data as $m){
            //echo 'mem code is:'.$v['memo_code'].'username is:'.$m['username'];
            if($v['memo_code'] == $m){
                echo " User: " .$m. " Time: " . $v['avg_handle_time'] . "<br>";
            }
            elseif( $v['memo_code'] != $m){
                echo " User: " . $m . " Time: N/A <br>";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So the first mistake is your use of `json_encode($user_data)` json encode is a function which converts an array into a string in the format of javascript object notation. It's to be used in conjecture with something like `echo json_encode($obj);` and recieved in javascript  `obj = JSON.parse(json);`

Now since you have 2 arrays what you need to do is loop through both to find the matching names:
I'm not sure what `memo_code` is but it needs to be a username.

Your query is incorrect change it to something like.

```
$result = $sql->query("SELECT username FROM `$table1`;");
  for ($user_data= array (); $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); $set[] = $row);

$result2 = $sql->query("SELECT memo_code FROM `$table2`;");
  for ($memo_data= array (); $row = $result2->fetch_assoc(); $set[] = $row);
```

Now you can finally use the loop correctly:

```
foreach($memo_data as $v){
    foreach($user_data as $m){
        if($v['memo_code'] == $m['username '])
            echo " user: " .$m['username ']. " time: " . $v['avg_handle_time'] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: memo_code(usernames) is the field name from where $memo_data is getting as you can see in the WHILE loop when declaring $memo_data array. I tried both of our codes and this is what I get : **user: A time: A
user: A time: A
user: A time: A
user: A time: A
user: A time: A
 time: B
user: B time: B
user: B time: B
user: B time: B
user: B time: B
user: C time: C
user: C time: C
user: C time: C
user: C time: C
user: C time: C**
  and it goes all the way to Z.. any ideas?

Comment: it still gives the same output?

Comment: do a echo statement under `foreach($user_data as $m){`echo 'mem code is:'.$v['memo_code'].'username is:'.$m['user'];` see if they are what you expect.

Comment: I added: **echo "testing loop";** under **foreach($user_data as $m){**  and the output is : **testing looptesting looptesting looptesting loop user: A time: A
** and it repeats

Comment: I tested your entire echo and I get this **mem code is:Ausername is:Mmem code is:Ausername is:Omem code is:Ausername is:F** which just outputs random letters.. this is really weird

Comment: yea the problem is your array, the `user` isn't an index it's just a string, which is really confusing and you don't need it.

Comment: Im not sure if I found the problem but is it possible that its trying to compare the 2 values of $memo_data. some have only username and others have username and time value

Comment: the var_dump($memo_data) gives me **[0]=> string(12) "ACKIS 692.33" [1]=> string(6) "ACMAN "** so it contains 1 or 2 values.. I took out the time value to see the difference but theres none

Comment: hmm... will see whats going on on SQL side. thanks for the help appreciate it

Comment: I cant do a SELECT on "table2" beccause my WHILE loop for memo_data has $dbh2_result as a variable that is calling a StoredProcedure **CALL telephony.sp_get_spec_stat_all_agents( 'start_date', 'end_date')** and I am replacing the parameters with values thats inside my script. So as you see the StoredProcedure returns every memo_code from the table. I can only run the Procedure for that server.